# pandas dataframe sort columns according to column totals

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I was able to sort rows according to the last column. However, I also have a row at the bottom of the dataframe which has the totals of each column. I couldn't find a way to sort the columns according to the totals in the last row. The table looks like the following:

```
   A  B  C  T
0  9  9  9  27
1  9  10 4  23
2  7  4  8  19
3  2  6  9  17
T  27 29 30
```

I want this table to be sorted so that the order of columns will be from left to right C, B, A from highest total to lowest. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by index value `T` with `axis=1`:

```
df = df.sort_values('T', axis=1, ascending=False)
print (df)
    C   B   A     T
0   9   9   9  27.0
1   4  10   9  23.0
2   8   4   7  19.0
3   9   6   2  17.0
T  30  29  27   NaN
```